# What are the effects of an all meat diet in cats?

Tags: cats, diet, safety, biology

Is there any harm in this or do I need to add nutrition to the diet? Also, how long would the health effects of a harmful diet take to appear and what are these, if any?

Comment: related https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/23575/is-it-possible-to-feed-a-cat-a-healthy-meat-diet?rq=1